# Kafka confluent platform 3.3 WARN Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

While starting Kafka standalone connector getting below error.

```
 WARN Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:589)
```

Kafka server zookeeper and confluent platform zookeeper are running on different ports. While using both in a same port leads to port already in use error.

Answer (score 1):

It worked after started two more brokers as instructed in [Kafka-Quick start](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)